# How do I use different profiles for development and production?

Tags: android, json, trigger.io

I have setup profiles in my local_config.json file as the documentation says, but when I enter a profile in the Tools page and try to run / package the application, I get the following error in the console:

`Expected to find object at profile; found release`

My local_config.json file is setup as follows:

```
"android": {
    "profiles": {
        "DEFAULT": {
            "keystore": "/path/to/debug-key.store",
            "keypass": "xxx",
            "keyalias": "yyy",
            "storepass": "zzz"
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "/path/to/prod-key.store",
            "keypass": "aaa",
            "keyalias": "bbb",
            "storepass": "ccc"
        }
    },
    "sdk": "/Developers/android-sdk-macosx/"
},
...
```

Has anyone managed to get this feature to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a rather under-used feature, and it does appear to be broken right now.

In the mean time the best I can suggest is keeping your release config in a separate file which you can copy in when you want to do release builds.